# document.getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know why it isn't working?

I want it to show div `odpoved` when I click on div `dotaz`.

```js
function ukaz(a) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dotaz" onClick="ukaz(odpoved)">
  <p>YOSODJDN</p>
  <span class="qanick">jirka</span>
  <span class="fafadown"><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="odpoved" style="display:none">
  <p>ODPOVED</p>
  <span class="qanick">anetka</span>
</div>
```

Comment: did my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this, pass `odpoved` as a string

```
<div class="dotaz" onClick="ukaz('odpoved')">
```

```html
<div class="dotaz" onClick="ukaz('odpoved')">
<p>YOSODJDN</p>
<span class="qanick">jirka</span>
<span class="fafadown"><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-down" style="font- 
size:24px"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="odpoved" style="display:none">
<p>ODPOVED</p>
<span class="qanick">anetka</span> 
</div>


<script>
function ukaz(a) {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onClick="ukaz(odpoved)"` is attempting to call a function, using a variable - instead of a string - as an argument.

```js
function ukaz(a) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dotaz" onClick="ukaz('odpoved')"> <!-- odpoved is a string, not a variable -->
  <p>YOSODJDN</p>
  <span class="qanick">jirka</span>
  <span class="fafadown">
    <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
   </span>
</div>

<div class="odpoved" style="display:none">
  <p>ODPOVED</p>
  <span class="qanick">anetka</span> 
</div>
```